# Give Logout url after changing name from Login to Logout

Tags: magento-1.9, module, layout, login, script

Once we click on "Login" button present in pop up, we want to change text "Login" to "Logout" present on top menu.

[image]

So i tried as [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwjYKy) , now i can able to change text from **"Login" to "Logout**" , along with this i want to give Logout url : `<url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>` , is this possible ?

> Login1 - pop up : app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme1/template/productlike - index.phtml

```
<form>
<input onclick="change();" type="submit" value="Login1"  />
</form>
```

**script**

```
function change() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("delUserButton")
    if (elem.value === "Login2")
        elem.value = "Logout";
    else
        elem.value = "Login2";
}
```

> Login in top menu [Login2] - app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme1/layout - customer.xml

```
<customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>             
            <![CDATA[<p><input  type="button" id="delUserButton"  value="Login2" /></p>]]>
            </label>
            <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title>       
            <prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="reorder"></remove>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to do more research before posting question , below code will make the trick :

```
<![CDATA[<p><a href="customer/account/logout"><input  type="button" id="delUserButton"  value="Login2" /></a></p>]]>
```